# webAPI return type

Tags: c#, .net, json

Should I always return the same JSON parsed object or not

Example :

On the website, the user enters his username and password.

When the user presses *Submit* he sends a request to `/api/logintest/{key}`. Should the method called by this URL return a JSON object like {errMsg: null} if the user and password match and {errMsg: "bad username or password"} if they don't; or I should return and error message if the user details don't match and return the user object in JSON if the user is found?

This is my code

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(User))]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/logintest/{key}")]
    public IHttpActionResult LoginTest(LoginForm luser , String key)
    {
        //test the api key
        if(key == "jordanisthebest")
        {
            //we try to get the user by his username and password
            User userReturn = UsersManager.getUserByEmailAndPassword(new User { Email = luser.Email, Password = luser.Password });

            //if the user is null then we return the err message
            if (userReturn == null)
                ModelState.AddModelError("Email", "Bad email or password");

            //if model state is not good we send err msg
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return  Ok(ModelState.getListErrorAndKey(null, typeof(LoginForm)));

            //if all good we return the user
            return Ok(userReturn);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you not sure what to return?

Comment: Away from the question, you should not use this way to authenticate users, you should authenticate your APIs using tokens issued by an identity provider such as ADFS or Identity Server

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know if they authenticate, then you could return:

```
{ "authenticated" : true } // or false
```

If you want to know the reason, so you can log it or display it:

```
{ "authenticated": false, "reason" : "User account was locked" }
```

To be more RESTful, you could make your route:

```
GET /api/users/{userName}/authenticate
```

Your "happy path" would return a HTTP status of 200 and the JSON message as the response content.

You could return a HTTP status code of 404 not found, if the user is not found (as the API call is looking for a user resource), but there would be no need to return a HTTP status code of 401, as the resource itself isn't the thing that the caller would be not authorised to use.

It is good practice not to expose to the user why they specifically failed authentication.  The more information you return to the user, is more information for hackers who might not even know if they have a valid user account.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it should not return a body but instead, return a HTTP 401 - Unauthorized

Sample code:

```
//if the user is null then we return the err message
if (userReturn == null)
    return Unauthorized();
```

Answer (score 1):

Another thing you can do is set up an authentication filter, so that credentials are checked after the request is made, but shortly before the actual endpoint gets called.

```
public class AuthenticationFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Your validation logic here.
    }
}
```

Then configure it in FilterConfig.cs:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AuthenticationFilter());
    }
}
```

...And you're set!